# Apache Camel 3.1.0 Logging Issue

Tags: apache-camel

While I was porting Apache Camel Version from 2.x to 3.1.0 with Camel REST DSL and Spring Boot, I am facing the below logging issue.

My logging key is defined in application.properties i,e mymessage=Hello World.
Inside route when I am using it as

```
.log(LoggingLevel.INFO, "${properties:mymessage}") [Works in both 2.x and 3.1.0]

.log(LoggingLevel.INFO, "{{mymessage}}") [Works only in 2.x]
```

My problem is I have lots of logging statements using {{xxx}} which is unfortunately not working during 3.1.0 upgrading process.

Am I missing any specific setting.

I tried using @PropertySource by putting the key in the separate file also tried it with spring cloud config nothing works.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This has been solved and will be part of 3.2.0, see https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-14651